# Javascript automatically submit form when input field is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to see if it's possible to submit a form automatically when a field is not empty. I have a 1 input fielded form which is a date picker. I am hoping that when the user selects a date it submits this value automatically.

Is this possible?

Cheers

I found a solution to it:

```
    <script>
   function myFunction() { 


var el = document.getElementById('input-datepick').value;
if (el!=""){

     document.getElementById('datepick').submit();

}

}

</script>
```

then on my HTML

```
<input onchange="myFunction()" name ="input-datepick" id="input-datepick"       
type="text" class="form-control datepicker">
```

Comment: "_Is this possible?_" -> Yes

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an EventListener to your input field and submit the associated form when the input field changes:

```
document.getElementById('id of your input field').addEventListener('change',function(){
    document.getElementById('id of your form').submit() 
}
```

Comment: CODE IN ORIGINAL POST.

I have got this far however when i changed the date the consle.log chaned works did not pop up. If I swap change for Click, it works, so there is something in the 'change' call that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

hood a function on date picker enter button.

use jquery .submit function if your input is warped in a form.

Another way could be use .ajax call pass your input value as ajax data.  is not needed in this approch